# How do I resize vector (only rows)

Tags: c++, c++11

How do I resize only row in 2d-vector ??

```
vector< vector<int> > matrix;
matrix.resize( num_of_row , vector<int>("I don't know how big the cols ") );
```

Comment: Is `matrix.resize(num_of_row);` not working for you?

Comment: I am just using C+98 ;; not C++11

Comment: You don't have a 2d vector but a vector of vectors. That's the root of your problem.

Comment: Why did you tag `c++11` if you're using C++98?

Comment: sorry for that.. ;;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `matrix` is not empty, you can get the number of columns from one of the rows of the matrix.

If `matrix` is empty, you will also need to provide the number of columns as input to the function.

```
if ( matrix.size() > 0 )
{
   size_t num_of_col = matrix[0].size();
   matrix.resize(num_of_row, std::vector<int>(num_of_col));
}
else
{
   matrix.resize(new_num_of_row, std::vector<int>(new_num_of_col));
}
```

If `matrix` is empty and the function does not have `new_num_of_col`, the best you can do is create a matrix in which all the rows are empty.

```
   matrix.resize(new_num_of_row);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save the existing column count before resizing. Something like:

```
auto num_of_col = matrix[0].size();
matrix.resize(new_num_of_row, std::vector<int>(num_of_col));
```

Answer (score 0):

`matrix.resize(new_no_col,std::vector<int>(old_no_col));`